# What does it mean if a wine is an "ex-domaine?"

Tags: wine

I believe this is a fairly simple question so I'm writing a lot here so the quality filter will allow me to post. I'm not sure what else to say besides the wine is listed as a variety (i.e. Chateauneuf du Pape) but specifically marked as an "ex-Domaine"

Comment: Where are you seeing this?  On a bottle label, in a catalog somewhere, someplace else?  (Knowing whether the label comes from the vineyard or a third party could help.)  Thanks.

Comment: I suppose it would be a catalog; it came from a stock list a distributor sent me. It's not clear if the winery labelled it like that or if the distributor did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think ex-domaine is the same as ex-chateau which means it's being sold directly from the producer to the consumer, something that almost never happens on a large scale in France. Mainly for collector wines that were held back and released many years later. Here is a definition of [ex-chateau](http://blog.vinfolio.com/2016/05/03/what-are-ex-chateau-wines/)

Comment: I think this is most likely the correct answer. I know the winery (Domaine du Mourchon) only ships to a few places here, so I think all of their wines are technically "ex-domaine" since they go directly to retailers.